# keyboard shortcut in google docs is same as safari

Tags: macos, safari, keybindings

Google Docs uses the <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> shortcut to apply subscript formatting, but I can't type this in Safari because <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> opens Safari's preferences.

How can I work around this?

Comment: Did you try ctrl instead? - many places that are non Mac-specific mirror the key commands to ctrl from cmd

Comment: @Tetsujin doesn't work

Comment: You should consider [reporting it to Google](https://www.google.com/tools/feedback/intl/en/). `Command` + `,` is the universal shortcut in macOS for opening app preferences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, <kbd>⌘Cmd</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> is almost universally the default keyboard shortcut in Mac apps for Preferences.

As I could not find any simple way of reassigning or customizing keyboard shortcuts for Google Docs, the best workaround is to override the system shortcut for Preferences instead, to avoid the conflict.    Thankfully this can be done easily in OS X:

1. Open System Preferences, and then the Keyboard pane
2. Select the Shortcuts tab. Click "App Shortcuts" on the left pane. Then, click the little "+" below the right pane to enter our own custom
   shortcut.
3. From the Application dropdown, choose Safari. (Or you can
   leave it as All Applications if you prefer to do a system-wide
   change).
4. For Menu Title, type `Preferences...` exactly, including the 3 dots.
5. Choose a different keyboard shortcut, preferably something not used by Google Docs. Perhaps <kbd>⌘Cmd</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>?

Once you've added the new shortcut for Preferences, you can use <kbd>⌘Cmd</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> for formatting subscripts in Google Docs!

[image: Adding a custom keyboard shortcut]

Comment: legend, this is the only thing that worked.

Comment: The above fix does not work for me. However, a [comment from webapps.stackexchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/133325/keyboard-shortcut-conflict-between-google-docs-subscript-and-mac-os-preferences#comment128048_133325) does the trick: use fn + command + comma in Google Docs.

Comment: This solution works, which is great, but it is completely insane on Apple's part that this is the only way to resolve this issue.